# Creating a custom QML Button with native look and feel

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt5.5

I would like to create a custom `Button` by defining my own QML type. This `Button` type should contain two text fields, one with a single character of a symbol font and the other one the actual button text.

That's simple, but how could I use the native colors, gradients, fonts and borders defined for the target system?

Is it possible to extend `Button` itself? And how would I disable the possibility to set an image when extending Button?

```
import QtQuick 2.5

Rectangle {
    id:anyButton

    property string image:"\ue43f"
    property string text:"Button"

    border.color : "black"
    border.width: 1
    radius: 5

    Gradient {
        id: lightGradient
        GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: anyButton.color }
        GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: Qt.darker(anyButton.color,1.5) }
    }

    Gradient {
        id: darkGradient
        GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: Qt.darker(anyButton.color,1.7) }
        GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: Qt.darker(anyButton.color,1.7) }
    }

    Rectangle{
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

        Text{
            id:buttonImage
        }
        Text{
            id: buttonLabel
            font.pixelSize:20
            text: anyButton.text
        }
    }

    signal buttonClick()

    MouseArea{
        id: buttonMouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: parent.buttonClick()
        hoverEnabled: true

        onEntered:{
            parent.border.width= 2
        }

        onCanceled:{
            parent.border.width= 1
        }

        onExited: {
            parent.border.width= 1
        }
    }
    gradient: buttonMouseArea.pressed ? darkGradient : lightGradient
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's quite simple in QML to create a button with custom style, text etc. 
With [`ButtonStyle`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-styles-buttonstyle.html) you can define custom [`background`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-styles-buttonstyle.html#background-prop) and [`label`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-styles-buttonstyle.html#label-prop) as you want. To get system colors use [`SystemPalette`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-systempalette.html). [Here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpalette.html#ColorRole-enum) you can find its application for real controls.

For example:

```js
Button {
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    property string firstfield: "a"
    property string secondfield: "sometext"
    iconSource: "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7"
    text: firstfield + " " + secondfield
    style: ButtonStyle {
        background: Rectangle {
            id: bg
            border.width: 1
            border.color: palette.mid
            radius: 3
            gradient: Gradient {
                GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: control.pressed ? palette.button : palette.light }
                GradientStop { position: 0.5; color: palette.midlight }
                GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: control.pressed ? palette.light : palette.button }
            }
        }
        label: RowLayout {
            id: row
            spacing: 5
            Image { source: control.iconSource }
            Label {text: control.firstfield; font.family: "Symbol"; font.pixelSize: 18; color: palette.buttonText}
            Label {text: control.secondfield; color: palette.buttonText}

        }
    }
}

SystemPalette { id: palette; colorGroup: SystemPalette.Active }
```

Sure, you can add a shadow etc. If you will drop the `ButtonStyle` it should look like a regular button

Comment: Thanks, but how can I prevent the user from setting a button icon and how could I keep the possibility to set a custom label layout. Your example doesn't really solve the problem. I am looking for a more generic solution.

Comment: @Avedo I think that whatever you do it's worthless. Consider this simple example: instead of modifying your button, I place an `Image` over it, not inside your button. Then I bound its `state` to your button `state`: that's it, I've mimicked a button with an image using your button. The component layering is up to the use and cannot be controlled.

Comment: I think you should to clarify your question. It's not entirely clear what you want to achieve